# My ajax form submits fine but I still get error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am sending a form for mailchimp with an email field, its being handled with ajax.

The form sends okay because I get a confirmation email from mailchimp but in my console I get this:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://markdunbavan.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=946312c950b11b5518…markdunbavan.co.uk&b_946312c950b11b551890e28f7_f3f7eb34b3=&_=1395094714933". jquery.js?body=1
```

The form is being sent from a rails app but that should not matter, here is my javascript:

```
var $form = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form');

            function register($form) {
              $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                cache       : false,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType    : 'jsonp',
                contentType: "application/html;",
                error       : function(err) { $('#notification_container').html('<span class="alert">Could not connect to server. Please try again later.</span>'); },
                success     : function(data) {

                  if ( data.result != "success" ) {
                    var message = data.msg.substring(4);
                    $('#notification_container').html('<span class="alert">'+message+'</span>');
                  } 

                  else {
                    var message = data.msg;
                    $('#notification_container').html('<span class="success">'+message+'</span>');
                  }
                }
              });
            }

            $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                register($form);
            });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I'd suspect this is your problem:

```
dataType    : 'jsonp',
contentType: "application/html;",
```

try this instead:

```
dataType    : 'jsonp',
contentType: "application/javascript",
```

Your content you're sending can't be HTML and JSON. It has to be one or the other. So Rails is warning you that it's confused but picking JavaScript over HTML as seen in the warning: `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html`.

Comment: yeah tried that but because mailchimps headers are html I cannot change that so I still get `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html`